# Here is a function I wrote that, with the help of jQuery, will randomize a bunch of properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's some code... please, be brutal

```
function twisty (elem, container) {
    elem = $('.some-elem');
    container = $('.container').hide();
    var spots = elem.text().replace(' ', '').split('');
    for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'spot '+ i,
        text: spots[Math.ceil(Math.random() * spots.length-1)] ,
        css: {
            fontSize: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50),
            left: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000),
            top: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30),
            bottom: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50),
            opacity: Math.random() / 3,
            color: 'rgb('+ Math.ceil(Math.random() * 70) + ',' +
                           Math.ceil(Math.random() * 70) + ',' +
                           Math.ceil(Math.random() * 70) + ')',
            transform: 'rotate(' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 360)  + 'deg)'
        }
        }).appendTo(container.fadeIn(800));
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
twisty();
$('.some-elem').on('click', function(){
    $('.container').hide();
    $('span.spot').remove();
    twisty();
});
```

});

Here's the html

```
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="some-elem">hello world<div class="container"></div></h2>
</div>
```

[Here's a link to the fiddle output](http://jsfiddle.net/laserface/NaDG5/11/embedded/result/)

Probably not the most useful piece of code, but some things I'm trying to learn are:

- How to extend native javascript objects (so how could i minimize the
  excessive use of calling Math.random)
- How to make my code as clean and as portable as possible
- How to animate stuff
- How to do all of the above without using jQuery
- How to extend jQuery

But mostly, I'm looking for feedback :]

edit: fixed so it actually fades in

(updated link to include some css, cause the transform prop wasn't working)

Comment: Lol, it's changed quite a bit.

Comment: yea, well, i'm new to jsfiddle, so needed to adjust it to be how it was locally.  but i'm done now, i promise.

Answer (score 1):

### Notes

I had a go at converting it to native JavaScript, was fun :P Pretty nifty bit of code. Here are my notes:

- I pulled `Math.ceil(Math.random() * x))` out into a function `randomInt(x)`, I recommend against extending native JavaScript objects. They tend to be difficult problems to debug, just create a new function instead.
- I would probably prefer to have `.container` outside of `.some-elem` or programmatically generated. I didn't make this change though. The main issue with having it inside .some-elem next to the text is that when you attempt to fill `spots` in JS you need to get rid of the `.container` markup from `.innerHTML` as it comes out like this:

  ```
  hello world<div class="container"></div>
  ```

  Which leads to a bit of ugly code to extract everything before the `'<'`:

  ```
  var spots = [].splice.call(elem.innerHTML, 0, elem.innerHTML.indexOf('<'));
  ```
- You can add the `speak: none;` to `.container` so [screen readers don't read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/672161/1156119) "hello world lakmsdlkaslkadsadfas...".
- You can extend jQuery like so:

  ```
  $.fn.customFunction = function () {
      console.log(this);
  }

  $('.some-elem').customFunction();
  ```
- I've used CSS3 transitions in place of `$.fadeIn()`, browser support isn't quite as good (looking at you IE), but the implementation is worth it in my opinion. Especially when most people wouldn't even notice like this super subtle fade in.
- I'm not so sure about adding a number as a class name, I don't think it's legal to have class names start with a number.
- Your indentation when you were applying everything to the `<span>` was a little ugly :P
- Overall it was a pretty decent and clean jQuery implementation.

### Code

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/UsAe8/3/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="some-elem">hello world<div class="container"></div></h2>    
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body { background: black; font-family: consolas;}

div.content {
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    min-height: 1000px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}


div.content > .some-elem {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-bottom: 7px solid #41919B;
    border-top: 7px solid #41919B;
    border-right: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-left: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px 11px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 11px;
    line-height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.content > .some-elem:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

span.spot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.container {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .8s ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity .8s ease;
    transition:opacity .8s ease;
    speak: none;
}

.container.show {
    opacity:1;
}
```

#### JS

```
function twisty(elemClass, containerClass) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('some-elem')[0];
    var container = elem.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
    var spots = [].splice.call(elem.innerHTML, 0, elem.innerHTML.indexOf('<'));

    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        var color = 'rgb('+ randomInt(70) + ',' +
            randomInt(70) + ',' +
            randomInt(70) + ')';
        var transform = 'rotate(' + randomInt(360) + 'deg)';

        span.innerHTML = spots[randomInt(spots.length - 1)];
        span.className = 'spot '+ i;
        span.style.fontSize = randomInt(50) + 'px';
        span.style.left = randomInt(1000) + 'px';
        span.style.top = randomInt(30) + 'px';
        span.style.bottom = randomInt(50) + 'px';
        span.style.opacity = Math.random() / 3;
        span.style.color = color;
        span.style.webkitTransform = transform;
        span.style.mozTransform = transform;
        span.style.transform = transform;
        container.appendChild(span);
    }

    container.classList.add('show');
}
twisty();

document.getElementsByClassName('some-elem')[0].onclick = function () {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
    container.classList.remove('show');
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    twisty();
};

function randomInt(max) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * max);
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the tips. Definitely cleaner with the randomInt function.  here's a question i have though... when I try to run this without jsFiddle, it doesn't work.  I know it has to do with using either document.onload or onready, but since I'm so used to using jQuery $(document).ready(), I have no idea what the correct way is to implement that using vanilla javascript.  (also, I got tired of correcting the indentation from jsFiddle).  your version has given me a good amount of stuff I didn't already know... so muchos gracias!

Comment: You can either put it at the end of the page just before `</body>` or throw it all in `window.onload = function () { /**/ }`.

Comment: when i use window.onload or document.onready, i get an error "Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined", when i use document.onload, it fails silently.  not a huge deal.. i can try and figure that bit out.  i want to try and keep the script in a separate document if possible

Comment: You can look at the markup that jsFiddle has produced, I turned jQuery off in this one and it has everything in `window.onload=function(){}` inside `<head>` http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/Y9msP/